# Pasar datos entre Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Tengo hecho un ViewPager, con pestañas para poder navegar entre los diferentes fragmentos (3).

Mi idea era tener en el primer fragmento una lista de CheckBox con los nombres de empresas, y que cuando deslizaras al segundo fragmento, en el que tengo un mapa (usando la API de Google Maps) se marcaran las chinchetas según los CheckBox que estén seleccionados en el primer fragmento.

El caso es que no sé cómo se pasan datos de un fragmento a otro.

Entre activitys si creaba un Intent y hacía `putExtra()` y `getExtra()` y eso.. . pero entre fragmentos no sé cómo se hace.

Answer (score 1):

En la documentación se tiene el articulo:
[Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Una solución sería enviar los datos por medio de una `interfaz`:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

y otra forma de enviar datos entre `Fragments` es enviar tu bundle, o datos cuando instancias otro `Fragment`:

```
public class myFragment {

public static myFragment newInstance(@NonNull final ArrayList<String> listaElementos) {
    myFragment f = new myFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle(); //* Bundle a recibir con datos.
    args.putParcelableArrayList("lista", listaElementos);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
} 


public ArrayList<String> getFoo() {
    final Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    bundle != null ? bundle.getParcelableArrayList("mi_llave") : null;
   }
}
```