# ¿Cómo pasar datos entre dos FRAGMENTOS?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Llevo un par de días intentando pasar los valores de los EditText del primer fragmento hacia los TextView del segundo fragmento, los fragmentos aparecen uno a la vez porque utilicé el Navigation Drawer Activity como base, ya he intentado utilizar Bundles e Intents, así como los .getActivity() y no he podido hacerlo funcionar, no se si es que los estoy poniendo mal, pero hasta donde anduve leyendo no me parecía estar dejándome nada, igualmente agradecería observaciones, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Aquí el código del fragmento con los EditText:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

private EditText nombre, hospital, telefono, especialidad, horario;
private TextView nombre2, hospital2, telefono2, especialidad2, horario2;
private Button continuar;
private MainActivity mainActivity;
private SlideshowFragment slideshowFragment;
public String f, g, h, i, j;

private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    nombre2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nombre2);
    hospital2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.hospital2);
    telefono2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.telefono2);
    especialidad2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.especialidad2);
    horario2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.horario2);
}

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

    nombre =(EditText)main.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    hospital =(EditText)main.findViewById(R.id.hospital);
    telefono =(EditText)main.findViewById(R.id.telefono);
    especialidad =(EditText)main.findViewById(R.id.especialidad);
    horario =(EditText)main.findViewById(R.id.horario);

    nombre2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nombre2);
    hospital2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.hospital2);
    telefono2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.telefono2);
    especialidad2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.especialidad2);
    horario2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.horario2);

    continuar = (Button)main.findViewById(R.id.continuar);

    continuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
            SlideshowFragment slideshowFragment = new SlideshowFragment();

            f = nombre.getText().toString();
            g = hospital.getText().toString();
            h = telefono.getText().toString();
            i = especialidad.getText().toString();
            j = horario.getText().toString();

            nombre.setText(f);
            hospital.setText(g);
            telefono.setText(h);
            especialidad.setText(i);
            horario.setText(j);
        }
    });

    return main;
}}
```

Y aquí el segundo con los TextView:

```
public class SlideshowFragment extends Fragment {

private EditText nombre, hospital, telefono, especialidad, horario;
private TextView nombre2, hospital2, telefono2, especialidad2, horario2;
String a, b, c, d, e;

private SlideshowViewModel slideshowViewModel;
private GalleryFragment galleryFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    nombre = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    hospital = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.hospital);
    telefono = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.telefono);
    especialidad = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.especialidad);
    horario = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.horario);
}

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slideshow, container, false);

    nombre2 = main.findViewById(R.id.nombre2);
    hospital2 = main.findViewById(R.id.hospital2);
    telefono2 = main.findViewById(R.id.telefono2);
    especialidad2 = main.findViewById(R.id.especialidad2);
    horario2 = main.findViewById(R.id.horario2);

    nombre2.setText(a);
    hospital2.setText(b);
    telefono2.setText(c);
    especialidad2.setText(d);
    horario2.setText(e);
    return main;
}}
```

Perdón por tener residuos de mis intentos de utilizar Bundles e Intents, espero que no sean distractores.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías utilizar interfaces para ello. Te adjunto un video un poco antiguo pero muy bien explicado. https://youtu.be/h1CYE02t3AU

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas, una de ellas es modificando tu Fragment destino, crea un método `newInstance()` donde definirías los valores en tu Fragment y dentro de `onCreate()` los asignas a variables para usar estos valores en tu `Fragment`:

```
public class SlideshowFragment extends Fragment {

private String nombre= "";
private String hospital= "";
private String telefono= "";
private String especialidad= "";
private String horario= "";

public static SlideshowFragment newInstance(String nombre, String hospital, String telefono, String especialidad, String horario) {

    SlideshowFragment f = new SlideshowFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle(); //* Bundle a recibir con datos.
    args.putString("nombre", nombre);
    args.putString("hospital", hospital);
    args.putString("telefono", telefono);
    args.putString("especialidad", especialidad);
    args.putString("horario", horario);

    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
 } 

 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       ...
       ...
       if(getArguments() != null) {
           nombre= getArguments().getString("nombre");
           hospital= getArguments().getString("hospital");
           telefono= getArguments().getString("telefono");
           especialidad= getArguments().getString("especialidad");
           horario= getArguments().getString("horario");
        }
       ...
       ...
       return rootView;
    }

 ...
 ...

}
```

Para instanciar el Fragment (desde `GalleryFragment` ) lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
//SlideshowFragment slideshowFragment = new SlideshowFragment();
Fragment fragment = (Fragment) SlideshowFragment.newInstance(nombre.getText().toString(), hospital.getText().toString(), telefono.getText().toString(), especialidad.getText().toString(), horario.getText().toString());
```

Revisa aquí dos métodos donde también puedes usar una interface: [**Pasar datos entre Fragments**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61309/pasar-datos-entre-fragments/61348#61348)